# I am unable to login

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, certification

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class testClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/onagssy/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/automation-demos/");
        
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"username\"]"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]"));
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Login"));
        
        username.sendKeys("lambda");
        password.sendKeys("lambda123");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.submit();
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}) on port 10883
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Feb 26, 2021 1:28:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: It ends up just reloading the page

Comment: Is the login works manually your submit locator is not workin

Comment: I changed it from login.submit(); to login.click(); and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to execute the code you have mentioned in the question's description and found that it wasn't able to locate the element Login button.

I modified the line to find the login button from,

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Login"));
```

To

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"applyform\"]/div/button"));
```

And it worked perfectly.

Here is the complete code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/milin/Milin/Tools/Automation/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/automation-demos/");

    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"username\"]"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]"));
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"applyform\"]/div/button"));

    username.sendKeys("lambda");
    password.sendKeys("lambda123");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    login.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
}
```